# Import Error Geocoding

Tags: python, geocoding, importerror

Here's my code:

```
import pygeocoder 
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
locations = Geocoder.geocode("Pacific")
print locations
```

Here is what it prints:

```
ImportError: No module named pygeocoder
```

Why isn't the importing working?

I am supposed to save the returned location data of Pacific to a variable called `results` but I have no idea what that means. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: You don't have `pygeocoder` in yours `site-packages`. Try `pip install pygeocoder .`

Comment: Did you install that?

Comment: Offical Python package installation guide: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html